# NPM how to install package as it was another

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, cordova-plugins

want to install package `com.cordova.plugin.cache` and its content i need it to be also as `cordova-plugin-cache`..

Example `package.json` was like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    // Note these two are the same but with different name 
    "cordova-plugin-cache": "git+git@gitlab.com:dev/library/org.git",
    "com.cordova.plugin.cache": "git+git@gitlab.com:dev/library/org.git"
}
```

But i published a modified version both of it on a private npm repository to remove the dependency as a repository.

```
"dependencies": {
    // Note these two are the same but with different package name 
    "cordova-plugin-cache": "git+git@gitlab.com:dev/library/org.git",
    "com.cordova.plugin.cache": "git+git@gitlab.com:dev/library/org.git"
}
```

Is this even possible? do i have to save both packages as they were two different?

Actually i have one package in a private npm registry, but don't want to duplicate the project.

Any hint is appretiated.

Answer (score 2):

NPM itself has no such feature, it was discussed on their GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2943) and it was decided not to implement such a feature.

The solution outlined in this [article](https://arunmichaeldsouza.com/blog/aliasing-module-paths-in-node-js) may prove to solve your problem:

You can utilise the [`link-module-alias`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/link-module-alias) module, add a `_moduleAliases` section to your `package.json` that describes the alias you wish to establish and then add a `postinstall` script that executes the aforementioned module.